# trying to define new variable 'year',For each date in df.date in python

Tags: python

trying to define a new variable 'year', for each date in df.date, am looking at YY = date.split('/')[-1].  If int(YY) < 19, record '20' + YY.  Otherwise record '19' + YY.
This is what I have so far, the problem with my code is that it makes all rows of the new variable 'year' 2015

```
df = df[df['date'].notna()]

for date in df['date']:
    YY = date.split('/')[-1]
    if int(YY) < 19: 
        df['Year'] = '20'+ YY
    else:
        df['Year'] = '19'+ YY
```

Comment: Please also include your data frame.

Comment: try `date.split('/')[:-1]`.  please paste some of your data if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
list_ = []
for date in df['date']:
    YY = date.split('/')[-1]
    if int(YY) < 19: 
        year = '20'+ YY
    else:
        year = '19'+ YY   
    list_.append(year)
df['Year'] = list_
```